# Is there any way to find out, which thread received the last input?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, input

I'm currently diagnosing an issue with window activation, where a call to [SetForegroundWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539.aspx) is failing, even though I believe it is being called from the foreground thread. The issue is reproducible when input comes from a touch digitizer.

Is there any way to find out, which thread received the last input? I tried calling [GetWindowThreadProcessId](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633522.aspx) on the handle returned from [GetForegroundWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633505.aspx). However, that appears to return outdated information, just after input activation of a window<sup>1)</sup>.

Since this is only for diagnosing an issue, I'm happy with a solution using undocumented interfaces, if public interfaces aren't available. In case this matters, the target platform is Windows 7 64 bit.

---

<sup>1)</sup> *`GetForegroundWindow` returns the same handle, irrespective of whether input comes from a touch digitizer or a pointing device. A subsequent call to `SetForegroundWindow` succeeds, when input comes from a pointing device, but fails for touch input.*

Comment: Can you just use Spy++ to see which window receives the last mouse message?

Comment: @JonathanPotter: Spy++ can only monitor messages for a single window, unless I'm not finding the particular feature you have in mind.

Comment: Did you call AllowSetForegroundWindow(ASFW_ANY) in your code before calling SetForeGroundWindow API ? We faced similar issue and calling AllowSetForegroundWindow solved the issue. [Note: Our issue wasn't specific to touch input]

Comment: @PraveenRaoJoginapally: I'm not calling [AllowSetForegroundWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632668.aspx), and don't see, how this could help either. This API merely passes on the privilege to call `SetForegroundWindow` to another window/thread. It can only be called from a thread, that is eligible to call `SetForegroundWindow` itself already. My issue is, that calling `SetForegroundWindow` is failing, and calling `AllowSetForegroundWindow` would fail just as much.

Comment: @PraveenRaoJoginapally: The `ASFW_ANY` parameter is something I can try, if I fail to diagnose the root cause. Thanks for bringing this to my attention.

Comment: Spy++ has an option to monitor all windows in the system. It's on the **Message Options** dialog in the *Additional Windows* section (at the bottom).

Comment: Looking at the SetForegroundWindow documentation, it is possible that the it is failing because the touch digitizer has called LockSetForegroundWindow to prevent a window change while the user is interacting via touch.

Comment: @Jeff: I'm not trying to prevent a foreground window change. I'm trying to set the foreground window to another window, from a thread that, for all I know, should be eligible to call `SetForegroundWindow`.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm: I'm going to have to investigate that. Touch input on Windows 7 is pretty flaky; I wouldn't be too surprised to see all sorts of hacks upon closer inspection.

Answer (score 1):

> Since this is only for diagnosing an issue, I'm happy with a solution using undocumented interfaces, if public interfaces aren't available.

You can try installing system wide hook for WH_GETMESSAGE with SetWindowsHookEx, and monitor interesting messages like WM_SETFOREGROUND. Ie. log interesting stuff before calling original version.

Another idea is to hook SetForegroundWindow API, with [MHOOK](http://codefromthe70s.org/mhook24.aspx) or [Detours](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/). As you can see here https://superuser.com/questions/18383/preventing-applications-from-stealing-focus, using mhook looks preety simple.

Comment: A `WH_GETMESSAGE` hook is called, whenever a message leaves an application message queue. I'm trying to find information about messages, as they enter the input queue. As for hooking `SetForegroundWindow`: I'm not trying to prevent anyone from calling it. It's just failing on me, even though I believe to be eligible to use it. I'm calling it from a window's thread, in response to touch/mouse input, and it exhibits the desired behavior for mouse input, just not with touch input.

Answer (score 0):

`GetWindowThreadProcessId` does **not** return which thread last received input for a window. It tells you which tread created the window and therefore **should** be processing the input.

You have to know that Windows input works via messages. These messages are delivered to a **thread** message queue. This explains directly why each window has an associated thread: that's the thread to which the message is delivered.

In a normal application, all windows are created by a single "foreground" or "UI" thread. Therefore, the question "which thread recevied the last input" is *always* "the foreground thread". Background threads simply do not receive window messages.

Very few applications create multiple windows on multiple threads, even though this is allowed. In those cases, two threads can simultaneously receive messages, which makes the notion of "last input" invalid. Each thread has its own "last input" in these cases.

Getting back to your stated problem, `SetForegroundWindow` has no documented thread restrictions. In particular, there is no restriction that it has to be called from the foreground thread. In fact, the documentation states that it can be another process altogether (which *certainly* means another thread).

You specially mention "last input", but the restrictions only mention that in process context: "A process can set the foreground window only if ... the process received the last input event".

Comment: Input in Windows works via **input queues**, not message queues. Input events enter the global hardware input queue, where they get picked up by the Raw Input Thread, then processed, passed to low-level input hooks, and finally signed off to the appropriate application's input queue. The process(es) owning the thread(s) of that queue is then eligible to call `SetForegroundWindow`. The documented restrictions are a condensed, dumbed-down version of the true restrictions, and they are quite obviously wrong. Each occurrence of *process* should read *thread or input-attached thread group*.

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer the question that was asked, but addresses the root issue that led to this question:

The [SetForegroundWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539.aspx) API imposes several restrictions on which thread can successfully call it. One of the prerequisites is that the calling thread's

> process received the last input event.

Unfortunately, on Windows 7 this does not include touch input. A process is not eligible to call `SetForegroundWindow` in response to `WM_TOUCH`. It is not until the system has synthesized a respective compatibility mouse input event, that the process finally gets foreground activation rights.

This has since changed, starting with Windows 8, where touch input counts as first-class input, and calling `SetForegroundWindow` succeeds in response to a `WM_TOUCH` message.